# Updating local /etc/hosts when talking to docker containers

Tags: java, maven, docker, jenkins

My maven POM file creates docker containers with services for testing. It also run the tests that must talk to services in those containers. Containers can talk to each other using host names defined as links in `docker-compose.yml` file, e.g.:

```
kafka:
  image: spotify/kafka
  hostname: kafka
  environment:
    ADVERTISED_HOST: kafka
    ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
  ports:
  - "9092:9092"
our_service:
    build: ../../logstash/
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    links:
      - kafka
```

This is because, `/etc/hosts` file of each container contains entries with links to other containers in the cluster. However, outside of the cluster, where Maven tests are run `/etc/hosts` is not updated and I don't want it to be updated because it will be run on Jenkins CI.

Sure, my tests could talk to Kafka through localhost:9092 but Kafka requires producers to connect to kafka host, not to localhost, if it has advertised under kafka name.

How can I solve this problem:

1. Run Maven tests in a docker container as well, but that would require Maven project to run another Maven project.
2. Update DNS cache for JVM programmatatically at runtime.

Both seems like a dirty solution to me.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your setup but what kind of tests are you doing? Are you trying to test the communication to kafka or trying to test your application? If so why do you need kafka? Can't you use mocks etc. ?

Comment: @khmarbaise I have an application A that reads data from Kafka, transforms them and sends to another application B. In my tests I mock the application B to verify whether is has received the right data.

Answer (score 0):

I'll give one suggestion (though, I'm not sure if the internals of Kafka will allow this).

You could use a DNS service such as nip.io to create a name for `127.0.0.1` like `kafka.127.0.0.1.nip.io`. You services would then become:

```
kafka:
  image: spotify/kafka
  hostname: kafka
  environment:
    ADVERTISED_HOST: kafka.127.0.0.1.nip.io
    ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
  ports:
  - "9092:9092"
our_service:
    build: ../../logstash/
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    links:
      - kafka:kafka.127.0.0.1.nip.io
```

Now, both outside and inside the containers your Kafka producers would connect to `kafka.127.0.0.1.nip.io` and Kafka should advertise itself as the same name.